# A relative motion question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relative-motion

A plane wishes to reach a destination that is 700km[S15°W] of its starting position. The plane can travel at 400km/h in still air. There is a 40km/h wind blowing from [W47°S]. What direction should the plane fly in order to reach its destination?

I know the vector equation should be something like pVa = pVg - aVg. Then you find the x and y components of pVg and aVg and then use the vector equation to find the x and y components of pVa. Then use Tan-1(y/x) to find the degree. But I got W0.34S. I want to ask what did I do wrong and how to solve this question.

[image]

Comment: You haven't asked a question.  You also haven't shown any work or thinking, which is required here for homework type questions.

Comment: Show your work. We cannot tell you what you did wrong if we cannot see what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is difficult to follow. However, in your last calculation -  finding arctan(-0.36) - the result of -0.34555 is in **radians** not degrees. You need to convert this to degrees (multiply by $\frac{360}{2\pi}$).

I have not checked everything so I don't know if this is your only mistake. You use an angle of $45^{\circ}$ although there is no such angle in the question.